# Java constructor?

Tags: java

Someone said to me this is a constructor, i am new to java and i thought a constrcutor has to use the word "new".

And can you please define constructor to me, i must have looked at over 10 definations but each one contradicts the other.

```
    this.token = token;
    this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.rank = rank;
```

Comment: Trying to learn the basics of Java by asking questions here is somewhat unproductive.  I suggest picking up a good introductory book, and reading the first few chapters.

Comment: This is not a real question. If there is a contradiction between *particular definitions* that is concerning, then post a question about *that* apparently contradiction, including sources.

Comment: Almost same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100432/java-code-explanation

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth would you mind recommending a book, from Amazon or anywhere. Thanks

Comment: @Stack Sack: It's highly possible that someone has already asked for Java book recommendations elsewhere on this site. Perhaps you could try searching for that question?

Answer (score 4):

That could the body of a constructor, definitely.

A constructor is a special method that's named the same as the class. You call it by using "new Classname", giving any arguments. It returns an object that you can then use.

Comment: No, of course it's not, but I was trying to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

See [Java: Constructors](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html) from Java Notes

> When you create a new instance (a new object) of a class using the new keyword, a constructor for that class is called. Constructors are used to initialize the instance variables (fields) of an object. Constructors are similar to methods, but with some important differences.

There are numerous introductory tutorials online for learning the basics (and even some advanced stuff) in any language, just look around. The above link was found searching for "java constructors"

In addition to that, the sample code you provided would be the *body* of a constructor but it lacks a class definition and other statements to *be* a constructor. The `new` keyword is used before an object to initialize it, which does call the constructor of the object you are initializing.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is similar to a method. Only it has no return type, and it has the same name as the class name:

Lets assume your class name is JavaApp:

```
public class JavaApp
{
    public JavaApp() // constructor
    {
    }

    public JavaApp(object token, int lineNumber, String fileName, int rank) // constructor, with 4 parameters
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public object token;

    public int lineNumber;

    public String fileName;

    public int rank;
}
```

Now all you need to do to instantiate your class, is this:

```
JavaApp app = new JavaApp(); // no arguments
```

or

```
JavaApp app = new JavaApp(null, 0, "", 0); // your specified arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is a particular method that creates a new istance of object

```
public class Test {
private int a;

//Constructor
   public Test(){
   }

//Constructor
public Test(int a ){
this.a = a;
}
}


//Usage example
Test a = new Test();
Test b = new Test(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor look very similar to a method, but has the same name as the java class and no return type.

Invoking the constructor requires que `new` keyword, but defining the constructor does not.

For instance if you have the class `Person` you could have a constructor like this:

```
public class Person {
     // this is the constructor 
     public Person ()  {
         System.out.println("This is the constructor");
     }
}
```

You could "construct" a new Person by invoking the constructor using the `new` keyword:

```
Person me = new Person();// you'll se the message "This is the constructor" in the console
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

a constructor is basically a method that initializes an object for your class.  when you create a new object (from a certain class), you call the constructor which creates the object with the settings from your input parameters.  in practice, the constructor doesn't have to actually do anything (i.e. you don't actually have to write code inside it).  it is just a convenient means of setting up your object.